# Google Scripts: Why do i always get a null return when using getEventSeriesById()?

Tags: events, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to go through an ical file and find where an event exists in my calendar that matches an event in my ical file. (I know for a fact that all of the events in my ical file do exist in my calendar) But when i run the search it can't find any, returning that none of the events exist....

I have even tried finding an event for today `getEventForDay()`, and directly feeding the ID of one of the events it returns straight back into the `getEventSeriesById()`/`getEventById()` and still it cant seem to find it.

Is this a known bug or am I doing something stupid here?
(Sorry, i have only been trying to get my head around this Google Script stuff for a day or 2!)

Here is my quick dirty function that just forces a known ID straight back in:

```
function quickCheck(){
  var myCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxx");
  var eventsToday = myCal.getEventsForDay(new Date());

  var evById = myCal.getEventSeriesById(eventsToday[0].getId())
  Logger.log("Desc test: " + evById.getTitle());
}
```

This just throws the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot call method "getTitle" of null."

Any pointers/insight would be appreciated!

**Edit:** To be noted: The events are all facebook events; it works if i create a standard google event!

Comment: It worked for me. Perhaps you id is incorrect.

Comment: Please double check that your Calendar ID is correct on assignment of `myCal`. It should include the `@group.calendar.google.com` or `@group.v.calendar.google.com` as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String))